# Why isn't the navigation showing from top to bottom but rather left to right

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Here is the snippet:

```js
const exitBtn = document.querySelector('#exitBtn');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
  for (let el of menu) {
    el.style.display = 'block'
  }
})
```

```css
@media (max-width: 934px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  .fa.fa-bars.menuBtn {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 110px;
  }
  .exit {
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    margin: 1.8rem;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <nav class="navbar" id="nav">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a id="headSpan" href="index.html">Port<span>folio.</span></a></div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars menuBtn" id="menuBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="exit">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle exit" id="exitBtn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

I tried making it block but it did not work, I also tried making flex-direction to be column but still did not work. Am I doing something wrong somewhere? What is causing the issue of the menu not being displayed from up to down? Is there an alternative way to go about this?

Comment: I dropped your code into a snippet and it seems to display as a vertical stack, so the issue isn't in the code you have included. Please try and create a snippet in the question that reproduces the problem.

Comment: ^ As DBS said I edited your post and changed the code blocks to a code snippet, and it appears to display in a vertical stack.

Comment: @DBS So the problem might be from google browser ?

Comment: It is unlikely this has anything to do with the browser. The problem is probably some code that you haven't included in this question, but exists on your real site.

Comment: You were right , I found the cause , In my code outside the query I added a more in-depth selector so it was taking priority over the code. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to set the position of the navbar class to fixed if it is a sidebar you are trying to do, or as how I perceive, you are trying to make a menu bar on the side supposedly and not a rowline. Then the class of menu should be the one flexed and not fixed. You are supposed to make a container for the menu that is the fixed one so that all of its content will be fixed on the side. Show me more of the css and I might help. But try doing

```
.navbar{
width: width;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;}
```

Then the "max-width" class will have the flex attribute

```
.max-width{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;}
```